# ADODB Cannot Find SharePoint Table

Tags: .net, vb.net, sharepoint, adodb

I'm having a issue writing to a SharePoint table I'm connection to via ADODB. I'm writing a vb.net app, and while this works on my machine, when I compile the project and release it, I keep getting the following error reported once deployed.

`The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Table_Name`

The adodb connection object is opening successfully, but when I call the `CommitTrans` or `.Execute` methods I'll get this error. The version of SharePoint is Office 365.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    Dim connection As ADODB.Connection = connectDb()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Try
        If Not connection Is Nothing Then
            Me.TextBox1.Text = "Connected"
            Me.Refresh()
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.Text = "Connection Failed"
        End If

        Dim i As Byte
        Dim AppendSQL As String = "Insert Into Table ([Count], [Date], UserName, AppName, WindowTitle, URL, ProductiveTime, IdleTime ) " & _
                                  "Values (1,#1/20/2017#,'','','','',1,1)"


        rs.Open("Select top 1 * from Table", connection, 2, 3)
        connection.BeginTrans()
        For i = 1 To 5
            With rs
                .AddNew()
                .Fields(0).Value = 1
                .Fields(1).Value = "Example"
                .Update()
            End With
        Next

        connection.committrans()
        MsgBox("Data should have been written to SharePoint")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Function connectDb() As Object
    Try
        Dim connection As Object = CreateObject("Adodb.connection")
        Const ListID As String = "{61C6957D-37A9-440C-A79D-A85D15C95F91};"
        Const ViewID As String = "{0C93F8A2-00FB-42E7-80A9-1FE82F7FAB3D};"
        Const ConnectionStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                                "DATABASE=https://mywebsite/sites/thesiteName/;" & _
                                "LIST=" & ListID & _
                                "VIEW=" & ViewID

        With connection
            .connectionstring = ConnectionStr
            .Mode = ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeWrite
            .open()
        End With
        connectDb = connection
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        connectDb = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. As it turns out I was using the 2007 redistributable Access engine with my installer. I noticed I was using 2010 on my local machine. Switching to the 2010 redistributable solved the issue on both machines.